# Acro package: `\acuseall` gives endless "LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right"

Tags: acro

As stated in the title, the use of `\acuseall` is giving me endless messages "LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right". So I believe that something is wrong.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage{acro}
\newcommand*{\acro}[3]{\DeclareAcronym{#1}{short=#2,long=#3}}
\acsetup{macros}
\acro{RAT}{RAT}{radio access technology}
\acro{CDMA}{CDMA}{code division multiple access}
\acro{OFDMA}{OFDMA}{orthogonal frequency division multiple access}
\acro{TDMA}{TDMA}{time division multiple access}
\acro{NOMA}{NOMA}{non-orthogonal multiple access}

\begin{document}

% Mark all acronyms as used
\acuseall

%%%%
\section{Spectrum Allocation\slash Trading}
\frame{%
    \frametitle{\insertsection: Traditional}%
    \framesubtitle{}%

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \alert{Dedicated licensed spectrum} 
        \item One operator, \ac{RAT}, etc.
        \item Orthogonality between different them, but 
        \item Shared (e.g., \ac{CDMA}) or orthogonal (e.g., \ac{OFDMA}) between users
    \end{itemize}
}

\frame{%
    \frametitle{Shared}%
    \framesubtitle{}%

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \alert{Shared licensed spectrum}
        \item At least two operators, \acp{RAT}, etc.
        \item Shared between them using time slots, i.e., \ac{TDMA}
        \item Shared (e.g., \ac{CDMA}), \ac{NOMA}, or orthogonal (e.g., \ac{OFDMA}) between users
    \end{itemize}
}
%%%%

%%%%
\frame{\printacronyms}
%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no warning if I place `\acuseall` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: It works. I was lazy not testing that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same behavior happens with the `article` class, so it seems a problem of timing in the processing of `\acuseall`.

Placing the command before `\begin{document}` seems to solve the issue. Probably the documentation should make this more clear.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is resolved in version 1.6 (2015/02/26) of `acro` which has been sent to CTAN yesterday and should be available soon in TeX Live and MiKTeX.

```
\usepackage{acro}[2015/02/26]
```