# LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right

Tags: bibliographies, citing, abnt

Why I am getting undefined references? The class `abntex2` based on `memoir` and it is available on https://github.com/abntex/abntex2 and CTAN.

```
[Compiling D:\test2.tex]

Basic Builder: running pdflatex...done.
running bibtex...done.
running pdflatex...done.
running pdflatex...done.

No errors. Warnings:

D:\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty: Package babel Warning: Last declared language option is `brazil',(babel)                but the last processed one was `english'.
D:\test2.tex:19: LaTeX Warning: Citation `ibge1993' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.
D:\test2.tex: LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

No bad boxes.

[Done!]
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    openright,
    twoside,
    a5paper,
    brazil,
    english
    ]{abntex2}

\begin{document}

Hello World \cite{ibge1993}

\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

**refs.bib**

```
@book{ibge1993,
  Address = {Rio de Janeiro},
  Author = {IBGE},
  Date-Added = {2013-08-21 13:56:10 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2013-08-21 13:56:10 +0000},
  Edition = {3},
  Organization = {http://biblioteca.ibge.gov.br/visualizacao/livros/liv23907.pdf},
  Publisher = {Centro de Documenta},
  Title = {Normas de apresentar},
  Urlaccessdate = {21 ago 2013},
  Year = {1993}}
```

---

## Update:

Now I included this:

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    openright,
    twoside,
    a5paper,
    english,
    brazil
    ]{abntex2}

% \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}

Hello World \cite{ibge1993}

\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

And get this problem `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`, every time I re-run. He is asking to re-run, I re-run, re-run, ... but does not fixes it:

```
[Compiling D:\User\Downloads\test2.tex]

Basic Builder: running pdflatex...done.
running pdflatex...done.

No errors. Warnings:

D:\SublimeText\Data\Cache\LaTeXTools\0604e8f81ec30badd38b80f0c41f7206\test2.bbl:3: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\uppercase' on input line 3.
D:\test2.tex: LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

No bad boxes.
```

I ran the command:

`latexmk -pdf -jobname=output -output-directory=cache -aux-directory=cache -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make test2.tex`

```
$ latexmk -pdf -jobname=output -output-directory=cache -aux-directory=cache -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make test2.tex
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c.
Latexmk: making output directory 'cache'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder -output-directory="cache" --jobname="output"  "test2.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
entering extended mode
(test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2.cls
Document Class: abntex2 2016/02/26 v-1.9.6 abnTeX2
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mempatch.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memhfixc.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bookmark.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bkm-pdftex.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty)

******************************************************
Stock height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Text height and width: 454pt by 278pt
Spine and edge margins: 85.35826pt and 56.9055pt
Upper and lower margins: 85.35826pt and 58.14961pt
Headheight and headsep: 12pt and 18.06749pt
Footskip: 25.29494pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 7pt and 42.9055pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 12pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 344.39996pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 12pt and 344.39996pt
******************************************************

) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2cite.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2abrev.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ltxmisc\relsize.sty))
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.aux)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
))
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label

LaTeX Warning: Citation `ibge1993' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.

No file output.bbl.
[1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10
.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
10.pfb>
Output written on D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.pdf (1 page, 21941 bytes).
Transcript written on D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Non-existent bbl file 'cache/output.bbl'
 No file output.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'cache/output.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `ibge1993' on page 1 undefined on input line 15
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/bibtex/bib/abntex2/abntex2-options.bib refs.bib]
Latexmk: 'pdflatex': source file 'cache/output.bbl' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "cache/output.bbl"'
------------
make: *** No rule to make target 'cache/output.bbl'.  Stop.
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex cache/output'...
Rule 'bibtex cache/output': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/output.aux'
   Non-existent destination files:
      'cache/output.bbl'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex cache/output'
------------
For rule 'bibtex cache/output', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ...
------------
Running 'bibtex  "output"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
The top-level auxiliary file: output.aux
The style file: abntex2-alf.bst
Database file #1: abntex2-options.bib
Database file #2: refs.bib
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Estilo bibliográfico abntex2-alf.bst versão v-1.9.6           |
| Em caso de dúvidas ou problemas com este estilo procure |
| http://www.abntex.net.br/                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/output.aux'
      'cache/output.bbl'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder -output-directory="cache" --jobname="output"  "test2.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
entering extended mode
(test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2.cls
Document Class: abntex2 2016/02/26 v-1.9.6 abnTeX2
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mempatch.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memhfixc.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bookmark.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bkm-pdftex.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty)

******************************************************
Stock height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Text height and width: 454pt by 278pt
Spine and edge margins: 85.35826pt and 56.9055pt
Upper and lower margins: 85.35826pt and 58.14961pt
Headheight and headsep: 12pt and 18.06749pt
Footskip: 25.29494pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 7pt and 42.9055pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 12pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 344.39996pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 12pt and 344.39996pt
******************************************************

) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2cite.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2abrev.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ltxmisc\relsize.sty))
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.aux)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
))
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label

LaTeX Warning: Citation `ibge1993' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.

(D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.bbl [1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdft
ex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\uppercase' on input line 3.

bibitemlist
) [3] (D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10
.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
10.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mss17.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.pdf (3 pages, 51786 bytes).
Transcript written on D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'cache/output.pdf'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `ibge1993' on page 1 undefined on input line 15
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/bibtex/bib/abntex2/abntex2-options.bib refs.bib]
Latexmk: Summary of warnings:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex cache/output'...
Rule 'bibtex cache/output': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/output.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'bibtex cache/output'
------------
For rule 'bibtex cache/output', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ...
------------
Running 'bibtex  "output"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
The top-level auxiliary file: output.aux
The style file: abntex2-alf.bst
Database file #1: abntex2-options.bib
Database file #2: refs.bib
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Estilo bibliográfico abntex2-alf.bst versão v-1.9.6           |
| Em caso de dúvidas ou problemas com este estilo procure |
| http://www.abntex.net.br/                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'cache/output.aux'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder -output-directory="cache" --jobname="output"  "test2.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
entering extended mode
(test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2.cls
Document Class: abntex2 2016/02/26 v-1.9.6 abnTeX2
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ifetex\ifetex.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\plain\ifetex\ifetex.tex))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mem10.clo)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\mempatch.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.st
y
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty
)) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\url\url.sty))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\memoir\memhfixc.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bookmark.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\oberdiek\bkm-pdftex.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\babel\babel.def))
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\babel-portuges\portuges.ldf))
 (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\enumitem\enumitem.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty)

******************************************************
Stock height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 597.50787pt by 421.10078pt
Text height and width: 454pt by 278pt
Spine and edge margins: 85.35826pt and 56.9055pt
Upper and lower margins: 85.35826pt and 58.14961pt
Headheight and headsep: 12pt and 18.06749pt
Footskip: 25.29494pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 7pt and 42.9055pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 12pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 344.39996pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 51pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 12pt and 344.39996pt
******************************************************

) (D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2cite.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2abrev.sty)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\ltxmisc\relsize.sty))
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.aux)
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty
))
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label
(D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.bbl [1{D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/data/pdft
ex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\uppercase' on input line 3.

bibitemlist
) [3] (D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )<D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss
17.pfb><D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mti10.pfb>
Output written on D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.pdf (3 pages, 42919 bytes).
Transcript written on D:\User\Downloads\cache\output.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'cache/output.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [D:/User/Documents/latex/texmfs/install/bibtex/bib/abntex2/abntex2-options.bib refs.bib]
Latexmk: All targets (cache/output.pdf) are up-to-date
```

---

Related:

1. [Document requiring infinitely many compiler passes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30674/document-requiring-infinitely-many-compiler-passes)
2. [Acro package: `\acuseall` gives endless "LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207339/acro-package-acuseall-gives-endless-latex-warning-labels-may-have-change)
3. [Label(s) may have changed run pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198517/labels-may-have-changed-run-pdflatex)
4. [Warning message with fonts: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285337/warning-message-with-fonts-labels-may-have-changed-rerun-to-get-cross-refere)

Related questions old:

1. [LaTeX Warning: Citation 'author2012' on page 1 undefined on input line 15](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78629/latex-warning-citation-author2012-on-page-1-undefined-on-input-line-15)
2. [LaTeX Warning: Citation 'aglarov02' on page 3 undefined on input line 9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370958/latex-warning-citation-aglarov02-on-page-3-undefined-on-input-line-9)
3. [LaTeX Warning: Citation `foo' on page N undefined on input line XX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152872/latex-warning-citation-foo-on-page-n-undefined-on-input-line-xx)
4. [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number)

Comment: How are you compiling? This warning is just logical for the run before bibtex. Your displayed warnings are in a very insignificant state.

Comment: I just call Sublime Text plugin LaTeX tools to build, but I am going to call `latexmk`. I ran `latexmk -pdf -jobname=output -output-directory=cache -aux-directory=cache -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make test2.tex`. Updated the question with the full log.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the culprit, but you do seem to have a missing (close) brace in your `ibge1993` entry.

Comment: Why are you using the -use-make option? There are no dependencies with rules to use it. I can get it to compile without it.

Comment: I just copied it from else where. I do now know what the `use-make` is doing.

Comment: I took it from the answer on [How to properly 'make' a latex project?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40738/how-to-properly-make-a-latex-project) and used it on my `Makefile`, so when I need to run a single command from the command line, I am using the same line and seems to be not causing problems.

Comment: Your life will be easier if you don't change the jobname, output or aux directories and if you don't use non-stop mode when debugging. Also, it is better to run `pdflatex` and `bibtex` yourself when troubleshooting.

Comment: Note that cross-references are not citations but references to other parts of your document e.g. 'section 1' is a cross-reference when it occurs in section 3.

Comment: if you just keep running pdflatex then this warning will of course not go, you need to build your reference list by using bibtex.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Do not put anything in build directories. It is a bad habit for LaTeX and makes your software screw up. Nothing good comes from it. You are hiding files which are very important.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I find out this problem is being caused by this:  `\renewcommand{\bibcite}[2]{\@newl@bel{b}{#1}{\hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#2}}}` on the file `abntex2cite.sty`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are the lines:

```
\renewcommand{\bibcite}[2]{%
 \@newl@bel{b}{#1}{\hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#2}}}%
```

On the file:

1. [https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/master/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2cite.sty#L547-L548](https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/15a981c300198ca59920eea17f02893490adf878/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2cite.sty#L547-L548)

Commenting them out on the latex installation removes the warning. Edit the
package `abntex2cite`, usually on:

`D:\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\abntex2\abntex2cite.sty`

and comment these lines:

```
% \renewcommand{\bibcite}[2]{%
%  \@newl@bel{b}{#1}{\hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#2}}}%
```

There is another question [Why \renewcommand{\bibcite}[2]{...} is causing LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386184/how-to-fix-renewcommand-bibcite2-causing-labels-may-have-changed-r) asking about what these 2 lines are doing and how to fix them.